# How to change the property value in a PropertyDecorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-decorator

How to change the value of `foo` in my `TestClass`, using the `DefaultValue` decorator?

```js
class TestClass {
  @DefaultValue('bar')
  private foo;
}

export const DefaultValue = (val: any): PropertyDecorator => {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol) => {
    // Change the value of the decorated property
    this[propertyKey] = val; // DOESN'T WORK!
  };
}
```

Won't work: `this[propertyKey] = val;`

Comment: Target is the prototype of the class holding the property (but I'm just beginning learning javascript/typescript... not 100% sure).

Answer (score 0):

you cant.

> that is because there is currently no mechanism to describe an instance property when defining members of a prototype, and no way to observe or modify the initializer for a property.

[~TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

Comment: What about defining a property with the same name on `target`?

Comment: It was an idea, can you elaborate it? I'm learning javascript and typescript, I'm really confused atm.

Comment: @gremo you could just `TestClass.prototype.foo = "bar"`, setting `target.foo = "bar"` will do the same